# report_uninitialized_variables output explanation

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I was trying the following code to initialise uninitialised variables in tensorflow

```
init_op = tf.variables_initializer([v for v in tf.global_variables() if v.name.split(':')[0] in set(sess.run(tf.report_uninitialized_variables()))])
sess.run(init_op)
```

However I kept getting errors related to uninitialised variables. Then I had a closer look to the output of `tf.report_uninitialized_variables()`
Executing the code

```
count = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, name='test')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print('local vars')
    print(tf.local_variables())
    print('global vars')
    print(tf.global_variables())
    print('uninitialised vars')
    print(set(sess.run(tf.report_uninitialized_variables())))
```

I get

```
local vars 
[] 
global vars 
[<tf.Variable 'test:0' shape=() dtype=int32_ref>] 
uninitialised vars 
{b'test'}
```

why is there a `b` before the variable name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `b` in front of the name is because you're using python 3 and the string in the result from `report_uninitialized_variables()` is actually a `bytestring`.

In python 3, defining a string with `''` (e.g, `'Hello'`) creates a *unicode* string. This allows for representation of all possible fancy accents, to the price of needing an encoding between the string itself and its *byte representation*.
A `bytestring`, on the other hand, is the *direct ASCII interpretation of the bytes stored*. To distinguish between a normal python 3 string and a `bytestring` you must **prepend a `b` to the string definition**, e.g.: `b'Hello I'm a bytestring'`.
When you print a variable value, similarly, the `b`is prepended as necessary to specify that you're dealing with `bytestrings` and not regular strings.